# netlogo simulating a sensor

Tags: netlogo, sensors

We are a group of 4 students simulating the movement of nanorobots and detecting cancercells in the bloodstream. We have a little dilemma. Our nanorobot is supposed to have a sensor to detect nearby cancercells. 
The parameters for the sensor is it has to be in a cone-shap pointing in the same direction the nanorobot is moving. The problem is that the sensor area is not supposed to be circular, but as mentioned, in a so called cone-shape
We want the sensor to detect only what is inside the cone-shape and during movement of the nanorobot.
It would be a huge help for us as we are fairly new to the netlogo program and are currently working on a project.

Comment: I just discovered the in-cone function but a new problem has arised. It cant detect the cancercells because it has to be from the same agentset. So how do i make my nanorobots detect the cancercells?

Comment: I think the documentation answers your question:
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/in-cone.html 
You just need to supply an agentset of cancer cells.

Comment: thank you very much for the help but i already looked into that. My problem is that my nanorobots are a breed and my cancercells are a different agentset. I dont know how to implement the nanorobots and cancercells in the same agentset.

Comment: Even if they are two different breeds, you can use `turtle-set` to create an aggregate turtle set, But from what you have said, I believe you are mistaken that you need to do this.

Comment: I figured out the problem myself by using another breed. I'm still fairly new to Netlogo so the concepts of turtles, agentsets, breeds and so on are still new to me and i dont quite fully understand them yet, but i appreciate the help :)